# Show that the derived subalgebra is a Lie subalgebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, lie-groups, lie-algebras

A (hopefully) very simple question that has been bugging me all day! 
Let $L$ be a Lie algebra then the derived Lie algebra $L'$ is

$$ L' = \{ \,  [u,v] : \forall u,v\in L \, \}.  $$

I want to show (without introducing the notion of an ideal) that the derived algebra $L'$ is a subalgebra of $L$.

Of course, to do this I have to show it is a subspace. And here is where I fall down, as I am struggling to show it is closed under addition. If $v_{1}, v_{2} \in L' \;\;\;\;$  then I need to show  $v_{1}+v_{2} \in L' \;\;\;\;$. We have

$v_{i} = [x_{i},y_{i}] \;\;$  for some $x_{i},y_{i} \in L$

then $v_{1}+v_{2} = [x_{1},y_{1}] + [x_{2},y_{2}]\;\;\;\; $, but in order to be in $L'$,  this must be able to be written as a single Lie bracket. Is this logic correct? Any pointers would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Usually the derived algebra is defined as the set of linear combinations of commutators, not just the set of commutators.

Answer (score 2):

The definition of $L'$ you have is wrong ; we usually take 
$$
L' \overset{def}= \langle \{ [u,v] \, | \, u,v  \in L \} \rangle_k
$$
where $k$ is the field of your Lie algebra $L$ (the brackets $\langle - \rangle_k$ means you take the $k$-span of the subset). Then your issue becomes trivial.

Hope that helps,

Comment: Ah perfect. I knew I must have gone wrong somewhere. And as you say, the result is now trivial. Thanks very much.

Comment: @DarnLieAlgebras : Note that if the underlying set actually *was* a subspace for some strange reason, then taking its span would result in the same object. So if we want this to be a subspace, this essentially solves our problem quite naturally!